# in android trying to create an image by taking the width and height of textview

Tags: android, canvas, textview

I have created my layout and textview dynamically and set the textview width to certain value and the hieght as fill_parent.

While doing

```
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("Hello world how are you whats up whats up hows life is good oh great");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    tv.setTextSize(24);
    ll.addView(tv);
    this.setContentView(ll);
```

its showing the content nicely and wrapping it correctly

Hello world how are you whats up
whats up hows life is good
oh great

but when i try to extract this textview width and height and try to create an image of same width and same height, its generating a smaller width image by cutting the Correctly word y partially.

```
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getWidth(),tv.getHeight(),Config.RGB_565);

    canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawARGB(255,0,255,0);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    paint.setTextSize((int) 24);
            canvas.drawText(tv.getText().toString().substring(0,44),0,27, paint);
    canvas.drawText(tv.getText().toString().substring(tv.getLayout().getLineStart(1),tv.getLayout().getLineStart(2)),0,48, paint);
    canvas.drawText(tv.getText().toString().substring(tv.getLayout().getLineStart(2),tv.getLayout().getLineStart(3)),0,48+24, paint);
    canvas.save();
```

Whats the problem.

I tried this too

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getWidth(),tv.getHeight(),Config.RGB_565);
        canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawARGB(255,0,255,0);
        final TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        paint.setTextSize((int) 24);
        canvas.save();
        StaticLayout sl= new StaticLayout(tv.getText().toString(), paint, bitmap.getWidth(), android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
        sl.draw(canvas);
```

But in the result i am getting a line cutting the text and an underline too. Please Advice

Answer (score 0):

TextViews word wrap.  DrawText does not, by design.  If you need that, you need to use StaticLayout to do the wrapping.

Comment: But i am trying to put the text one by one and how this is possible with Static Layout.. can you please provide me any example

Comment: bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getWidth(),tv.getHeight(),Config.RGB_565);
  canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
  canvas.drawARGB(255,0,255,0);
  final TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Color.BLUE);
  paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
  paint.setTextSize((int) 24);
  canvas.save();
  StaticLayout sl= new StaticLayout(tv.getText().toString(), paint, bitmap.getWidth(), android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
     sl.draw(canvas);